# Multiple document.createElement with eventListeners in One Function Return?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have a function that returns something into the dom (a cellrenderer in ag-grid). Is it possible to create two different elements with document.createElement(), attach event listeners with addEventListener(), and return them in a single function?

For instance, this works, but I need to return two elements:

```
function() {

  var el = document.createElement('input');

  el.addEventListener('click', function () {
       console.log("el clicked");
  });

  return el;

}

//returns <input/> into the dom, and attaches eventlistener
```

Here is what I'm trying to do. The only way I have been able to get it to return html is by adding outerHTML methods on the return, but it doesn't seem to add the event listeners that way. If you take off .outerHTML it will return [object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLButtonElement]

```
function() {

  var el = document.createElement('input');
  var el2 = document.createElement('button');

  el.addEventListener('click', function () {
       console.log("el clicked");
  });
  el2.addEventListener('click', function () {
       console.log("el2 clicked");
   });

  return el.outerHTML + el2.outerHTML

}

//want this to return <input/><button/> with eventlisteners attached
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the events are attached to the dom element, when you get the html markup of those elements the attached handlers are lost.

You can return a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) which contains both the elements like

```js
function x() {

  var el1 = document.createElement('input');

  var el2 = document.createElement('button');
  el2.innerText = 'Button';

  el1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    snippet.log("el1 clicked");
  });
  el2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    snippet.log("el2 clicked");
  });

  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  fragment.appendChild(el1);
  fragment.appendChild(el2);
  return fragment;

}

document.body.appendChild(x())
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

If you want to return the html, then you can use the `onclick` attribute like

```js
function x() {

  var el1 = document.createElement('input');

  var el2 = document.createElement('button');
  el2.innerText = 'Button';

  el1.setAttribute('onclick', 'el1click()');
  el2.setAttribute('onclick', 'el2click()');

  return el1.outerHTML + el2.outerHTML

}

function el1click() {
  snippet.log("el1 clicked");
}

function el2click() {
  snippet.log("el2 clicked");
}

ct.innerHTML = x();
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<div id="ct"></div>
```